# why hard coded value work on button and not work on another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have two button both have same code only difference is parameter .One function give correct out put and other give undefined.?
I am using jstree in my demo .

First Button is "child" where I hard coded "b" and get the child value.
Second Button is "next" where I hard coded "c" and get the child value undefined.
Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/69/

```
    $('#next').click(function () {


            $('#tree').jstree(true) .select_node('c')

            alert($('#tree').jstree(true).get_node( 'c').children);



    });


$('#child').click(function () {
    $('#tree').jstree(true) .select_node('b')
    alert($('#tree').jstree(true).get_node('b').children)
for(i in $('#tree').jstree(true).get_node('b').children){    //alert($('#tree').jstree(true).get_text($('#tree').jstree(true).get_node('b').children[i.toString()]));
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the **id** from

```
<li id="c-1">c
```

to

```
<li id="c">c
```

Comment: @lessuger can we get id of select id ? or which have active class

Comment: Not sure I fully get what you're asking, but in general you can get ID of whatever element you need. If this doesn't cover your question, please elaborate a bit.